# AngularJS - Custom Directive - Appending children doesn't work

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I am trying to create a custom directive which builds up DOM in a way similar to how you would do it in jQuery. However, I cannot get it to work. AngularJS's element.append() removes all HTML in the string passed to it. Here is my code so far:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">


<head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.5/angular.min.js">    
    </script>
</head>

<body ng-app="myapp">

<div ng-controller="myController">

    <table tasklist="123">

    </table>

</div>


<script>
var module       = angular.module("myapp", []);

module.directive('tasklist', function($compile) {
    var directive = {};

    directive.restrict = 'EA'; /* restrict this directive to attributes */

    directive.link = function($scope, element, attributes) {
        console.log("directive link() running");

        // Add tr rows inside table element.
        // You can use jQuery DOM methods on the element object.
        for( var i=0; i < $scope.data.taskList.length; i++) {
            var rowStr = "<tr><td>" + $scope.data.taskList[i].taskTitle + "</td></tr>";

            $compile(rowStr)($scope, function(cloned, scope)   {
                element.append(cloned);
            });

        }
    }


    return directive;
})

var myController = module.controller("myController", function($scope) {

    console.log("myController running") ;
    $scope.data = {};

    $scope.data.taskList = [];

    $scope.data.taskList.push({ taskId : "1", taskTitle : "First task 1"});
    $scope.data.taskList.push({ taskId : "2", taskTitle : "Second task"});
    $scope.data.taskList.push({ taskId : "3", taskTitle : "Third task"});


});



</script>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Have you tried to simply use ng-repeat?

Comment: Yes, I can easily get it to work using ng-repeat. However, I want this to be possible with AngularJS directives too.